# How to detect height from top/bottom of page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm wanting to write a directive as a learning experience.  I thought it would be simple to write one which would place either a header or footer on the page.  I could set an attribute for "header" or "footer" and it would add the relevant template to the page.  What I would like to know is how would I detect when the user has scrolled say 50px down the page?  Once I know the user has scrolled this far I can place my header or footer on the page depending on which direction they scroll.

Comment: Question seems a bit premature ... try writing it and when you run into actual code issues ask questions. It's not hard to find out how to track scroll position. Get that part working first, then integrate the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject $window service and use `$window.screen.height/width`

For detecting scroll position use `$window.scrollX/Y`